# Codeigniter Pagination

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-3

Can any one tell me wahat went wrong here. I am writing a code for pagination using codeigniter pagination library and every thing works perfect except the page links donot take any where. they just add additional uri paths like http://localhost:8081/web/index.php/Public/Main/index/1/1/1 when clicked. Help please.

application/core/ My Controller

```
public function PAGINATE($total, $per_page) {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config["base_url"] =   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $config["total_rows"] = $total;
        $config["per_page"] = $per_page;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $config["num_links"] = 3;
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
        die(print_r($config));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    }
```

Controllers/Public/Main/Index

```
public function index()
    {
        parent::PAGINATE(sizeof($this->data['homes'] = $this->AppModel->get_all(HOME_TABLE, 200, 0)), 1);
        parent::RENDER('Public/Site/Home');
    }
```

Model

```
 public function get_all($table, $limit, $offset){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $this->db->from($table);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array(); // fetch data

    }
```

View

```
<div class="page-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><?php echo $links; ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: how many records in the table?

Comment: Try with hard coded value for base url similar to how is pointed in [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html#example) ( `http://example.com/index.php/test/page/` ). Don't forget ending slash.

Comment: ImBS  10 records are in the table.

Comment: @Tpojka i treied that and nothing is changed.

Comment: Problem is that relative links are created and those are appending existing URL. Can you post what is there in `$links` variable when page is rendered?

Comment: $x= $this->data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        die(print_r($x));  it gives the ff result  1234NextLast1

Comment: I meant of [rendered output](view-source:http://localhost:8081/web/index.php/Public/Main/index/) an please, post it in edited question, not in comment itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$config["base_url"] =   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

This line should be replace with following

```
$config["base_url"] =   site_url('public/main/index');
//$config["base_url"] =   'http://localhost:8081/web/index.php/Public/Main/index';//you can use this too
```

Make sure you loaded `URL` helper to use `site_url` function.

If you want to see page number instead of record number in link you can use

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = true;
```

To get total records in database you should use.

```
return $this->db->count_all_results($table);
```

For more details please refer **[doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html)**.

Comment: I have wrote tutorial about Cdeigniter Pagination. Please have a look and give your suggestions https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/